# How to conditionally show a URL in jQuery in response to an AJAX fetch?

Tags: jquery

What I want to achieve: if the Url for certain employees does not exists then instead of displaying an error page I do not want to show the link itself for that employee. I have done it in 2 different ways and none of them are working.

I have the entire code below. All of it is working except for the url part for ones with no html page that my link can connect to.

```
function test(a,b) {

    var Name = a.text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "EmpServices.asmx/GetInfo",
        data: '{ "fieldName": "' + a.attr("id") + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(results) {
            //            if (results.d.Url.length < 2)
            //            {
            //               $('#url').hide();
            //            }
            if (results.d.EmpName.length > 1) {
                var html = '<div style="width:25%;"><img src="' + results.d.image + '" /></div>'
                    + '<div  style="width:75%;">'
                    + '<div><h3>' + results.d.EmpName + '</h3></div>'
                    + '</div>';
                //+ '<div id="url"><a href="' + results.d.Url+ '">Info></a></div>';

                if (results.d.Url.length < 2) 
                {
                    html += '<div id="url"><a href="' + results.d.Url+ '">Info></a></div>';
                }
                $(Employee).html(html);

            }
        },
        error: function() {
            $(Employee).html('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: What is a value of results.d.Url.length?

Comment: Let me check in firebug. But it should be like an http:// address

Comment: So I checked that in 1 case the length was 76 and regarding the data. I need to add style but at this point it is the employee picture, Name, url which will take to employees page if it was created by the employee otherwise the url will not exists and will have null

Comment: Okay. Yes you are right. I had in the development had junk values in Url and so that's why it was always > 2 and therefore showing erroneous output. But there is an issue about the closing div tag for style width:75%. It should come after url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the server-side code yourself? If you did, and you can modify it to return an empty string `('')` instead of `null`, if a URL doesn't exist, you could replace this:

```
if (results.d.Url.length < 2) 
{
   html += '<div id="url"><a href="' + results.d.Url+ '">Info></a></div>';
}
```

with this:

```
if (results.d.Url) 
{
   $(html).append('<div id="url"><a href="' + results.d.Url + '">Info></a></div>');
}
```

The `$(html).append(...)` takes care of inserting the URL within the enclosing DIV.

Answer (score 1):

You cant call `$('#Url').hide()` there because you havent added it to the dom yet, do something like this:

```
var Name = a.text();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "EmpServices.asmx/GetInfo",
    data: '{ "fieldName": "' + a.attr("id") + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results) {
        if (results.d.EmpName.length > 1) {
            var html = '<div style="width:25%;"><img src="' + results.d.image + '" /></div>'
                + '<div  style="width:75%;">'
                + '<div><h3>' + results.d.EmpName + '</h3></div>'
                + '</div>';

            if (results.d.Url.length >= 2)
            {
                 html += '<div id="url"><a href="' + results.d.Url+ '">Info></a></div>';
            }



            if (results.d.ProductUrl.length < 2) 
            {
                html += '<div id="url"><a href="' + results.d.Url+ '">Info></a></div>';
            }
            $(contentElement).html(html);

        }
    },
    error: function() {
        $(contentElement).html('Error');
    }
});
}
```

What im doing here is instead of adding a url div, then trying to hide it, just don't add the div if you dont have the url!

Comment: @Andrew Good point. Thats why i did it in 2 different ways. But it is still having no effect. Also, the closing </div> tag with style="width:75%" should close after the url is displayed. Thats another issue I am having. Please advice